# Characterizing certain kind of infinite dimensional algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},2^{1/5},2^{1/7},\dots),$ then $K$ is an infinite dimensional algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}.$ Now $i$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q},$ so $i \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}},$ the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. But $K \subset \mathbb{R},$ so $i \notin K.$ Thus $K$ is a proper subset of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

**My question:** Is it possible to characterize all infinite algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, properly contained in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$? In other words is it possible to give an algebraic characterization of the following set $$\mathcal{F}=\{K \subset \mathbb{C} \text{ ; $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is algebraic and $K \subsetneq \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$} \}.$$

Comment: I suppose they are the fixed fields of the non-trivial closed subgroups of the absolute Galois group with infinite index. Would that be algebraic enough for you?

Comment: I am unable to understand your comment, can you please explain a little more? So absolute Galois group is the Galois group of the separable closure of $\mathbb{Q},$ now what is a closed subgroup?

Comment: @RioDutta The absolute Galois group (of a number field) has a natural topology, under which only closed subgroups obey the Galois correspondence.

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph, so isn't non-trivial closed subgroups of the absolute Galois group with infinite index just another way of describing what I have asked? Is it possible to find out all such closed subgroups? Then that will solve my problem.

Comment: @TokenToucan I have taken just the real roots of the polynomial $x^n - 2.$